# How does compiler fetch elements from array of objects in constant time?

Tags: arrays, compiler-construction

Whenever we want to fetch elements based on index from an array, I learned that the compiler just does something like this to fetch the element in constant time:

`array_addr + ele_size * (i - first_index)`
(where the `ele_size` depends on the type of the elements present in an array, e.g. for `array[int]` the `ele_size` will be 4 bytes)

So how does compiler fetch elements from `array[object]` in constant time, **when each `object` could have a different size** (in memory)?

PS: Question is not specific to any language

Comment: It doesn't. The code it geneates does, using the instruction set of the processor. There is nothing in the expression you provided that cannot execute in constant time. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array[object]` and `array[int]` are actually very similar, since an array of objects doesn't usually store the actual objects directly next to each other like this:

```c
// [ _______Person________,  _____Pet_____,  _______Person_______ ]
   [ Name,    Age, Country,  Name,    Type,  Name,   Age, Country ]
   [ "Lucas", 37,  FRANCE,   "Misty", CAT,   "Emma", 22,  SWEDEN  ]
```

Instead, the array just stores references (pointers to the objects), which are all of the same size (32 or 64-bit int):

```c
// [ ______Person______,  ________Pet_______,  ______Person______ ]
   [ address of Person,   address of Pet,      address of Person  ]
   [ 0xaba11b8ae55fa4d2,  0xb8e4f4adea6be036,  0x5ce415a69ca50222 ]
```

Then the data for each object is found at the specific memory address and can occupy however many bytes is needed.

You might find [this question about how `object[]` is stored in memory (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118511/how-is-an-array-of-objects-stored-in-memory) useful.

Answer (score 0):

> So how does compiler fetch elements from `array[object]` in constant time (as the size of the objects could vary)?

Well, the expression that is being evaluated is:

```
array_addr + ele_size * (i - first_index)
```

where `ele_size` is a constant that depends on the (compile time) type of the array, and `first_index` is also typically a constant; e.g. zero for C, C++, Java, etcetera.

That is one subtraction (when `first_index` is not the constant zero), one multiplication, one addition, and possibly a memory fetch or two.

Either way, the **number of machine instructions** required to perform the calculation is a constant.  Hence (modulo quibbling about variable memory fetch times, pipeline effects, etc) the time taken for one such computation will be a constant ... irrespective of the values of the notional expression parameters.

---

<sup>Quibble:  The compiler doesn't fetch the elements.  It *generates code* that will fetch elements ... when the code is executed.</sup>